# Any best practices to create dbcontext in Entity framework using MSAL authentication to connect Azure SQL server?

Tags: iis, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, unity-container, .net-framework-version

1. We are generating token to connect SQL server using MSAL authentication.
2. For Entity framework we have registered the constructor in unity.
3. We are using PerThreadLifetimeManager() which will creates singleton dbcontext object per thread. and it only returns different objects from the Unity container only on different threads. Adding PerThreadLifetimeManager() reduces the PLT time but not as existing one.
   e.g. In existing system for 100 calls the PLT is 8-10 secs. With the current approach implementation, it is taking 30-35 secs. Without PerThreadLifetimeManager() it is taking ~4 mins for 100 calls.
4. There are some places where we cannot use PerThreadLifetimeManager() over there we are getting below exception.
   Error:A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   References: https://www.cloudockit.com/azure-ad-authentication-with-azure-sql/
   https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/lifetime-manager-in-unity-container

[image]
In the above image GetsqlConnection create connection object.